# New kernel won't boot, cannot get to a grub screen with choice of old kernels

Tags: boot, bootloader

This question involves needing a better understanding of UEFI booting also. I just installed Kubuntu 16.04.1 from usb iso image (live CD) onto a new computer (I-7, 6700K, Asus 170AR motherboard, M.2 SSD drive) and after getting nvidia 370.26 module it was working fine until a kernel upgrade to 4.4.0-59. It wouldn't boot, frozen at "kubuntu" on screen at startup. Trying different boot options from UEFI/Bios didn't work. I needed to put usb live CD in boot to that and then run synaptic to remove new kernel leaving 4.4.0-57. It could be a graphics driver issue (but on 14.04 LTS every kernel upgrade worked with the nvidia drivers). But the main issue is for problems like this how can I get it to boot to old kernel or console so I can work things out. A good source for information on UEFI booting with only one distribution (Kubuntu/or Ubuntu only) would be useful. I am booting with secure boot and fast boot disabled.

Comment: What is the question? You could boot to a previous kernel using grub menu and remove the bad kernel. How did you install the Nvidia driver? Version is weird. It is not either 367 that is in the repos, not the latest.

Comment: To further [your  understanding.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)